# Trying to use a parameter obtained from Index() controller and passing it into KendoGrid to retrieved items associated with the parameter(an id)

Tags: url, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

A bit of background. I'm working with MVC and I've appended an ID to my path so that when I pass the ID to my controller, the controller will look through a database and look for another ID that is in the same row as the ID I just passed in.

I then redirect to my Index() controller with these two IDs now present in the query string and I return the view.

My problem is that I want to that I want to link up the the second ID that I found in my Index to another controller that is associated with the Kendo UI's kendo grid create operation. I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Don't hesitate to ask me for more details. Thanks.

Example urls:
localhost/Customs/Invoicered?bcID=7SJF82NF-VFDF-83NN-SD3V-92HFN7FH4NRM

localhost/Customs/Invoice??bcID=7SJF82NF-VFDF-83NN-SD3V-92HFN7FH4NRM&trx=DSF83JFN-SDFM-32FS-8DJS-SDK36DK3332M

EDIT: Go to this link for the way I solved it. [Passing data in view model to controller via kendo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246335/passing-data-in-view-model-to-controller-via-kendo-grid/40246923?noredirect=1#comment67761751_40246923)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return the 2 IDs in a ViewModel, then in the View, add the ID to the configuration of the grid's Read action:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id1, int id2)
{
    return View(new MyViewModel()
    {
        ID1 = id2,
        ID2 = id2
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.Kendo().Grid<MyGridViewModel>()
    ...Other Grid setup...
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "MyController")
            .Data(new { id2 = @Model.ID2 })
        )
        ...Other DataSource setup
    )
)
```

And then have your read action on the server take an "id2" parameter.

```
public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id2)
{
    // Do whatever you need with id2...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I was pretty stumped. I've never used viewmodels before and I'm wondering if you could help a bit more. I'm using asp.net, so I think that's why my syntax is different than yours.

Comment: I created a viewmodel with two properties: id and id2 for bcid and trx respectively. Since, I'm not too familiar with viewmodels, I declared a new view model and I'm trying to add the params into ids, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Dim myViewModel As New MyViewModel With {id = bcID, id2 = trx}

Comment: Yeah, my syntax was C# and you are using VB.NET, but a ViewModel is just a class that give to a View and tell it, "use this as your Model of the data you are displaying".

Comment: Also, I found documentation on Telerik for passing the viewmodel into kendo grid.

Comment: @Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>.Name("kendogrid")   For some reason, I keep getting an error saying kendo is not a member of htmlhelper

Comment: I just got it working. I'm not sure how, but it stopped after installed a resources file from the telerik folder I downloaded. However, .Grid is throwing an exception. Type parameter <T> for public overridable overloads function grid(of T as a class) as a gridbuilder(of t) cannot be inferred.