# Passing data in view model to controller via kendo grid

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

So far, I'm just trying to instantiate my kendogrid and passing through values from my view model. I got the following piece of code from Telerik's documentation for vb.net. The thing is, an exception is thrown from .Grid ->
"Type parameter  for public overridable overloads function grid(of T as a class) as a gridbuilder(of t) cannot be inferred"

Html.Kendo().Grid().Name("kendogrid")

I'm not sure what this error means and I don't know how to go about fixing it.

View

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "TestAjax",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
            },
            update: {
                url: "update",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            create: {
                url: "CreateInvoiceRecord",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                console.log(operation);
                console.log(options);
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        },
        batch: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "itemID",
                fields: {
                    ItemName: { type: "string" },
                    Amount: { type: "number", editable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                    ProductLine: { type: "string" },
                    Status: { type: "string" },
                }
            }
        },
        aggregate: [{ field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }
        ]
    });
    $("#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
        DataSource: dataSource,
        pageable:  true,
        height: 550,
        toolbar: ["create", "save"],
        columns: [
            { field: "ItemName", title: "Item", width: "150px" },
            { field: "Amount", title: "Amount", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px", aggregates: ["sum"], footerTemplate: "Total Amount: #=sum#" },
            { field: "ProductLine", title: "Product Line", width: "150px", editor: productLineDropDownEditor},
            { field:  "Status", title: "Status", width: "150px", editor: statusDropDownEditor },
            { command:  "Update", title: "Update" , width:"150px"}],
        editable: true
        });
});
```

Model

```
Public Class MyViewModel
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property id2 As String
End Class
```

Comment: you need to make sure that the model list that your controller is returning to the Grid's read method is right.  For example, if your columns are "name", "age", "sex" then the model from the controller has to match exactly "name", "age", "sex", case sensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you give me an example or go a bit more into depth? I've also added my kendo code if that helps you in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got what I wanted working using a hack for create and then ajax for read. Not totally sure why this works the way it does so I'll need to look into it some more. I needed to pass parameters to controllers that are connected to kendogrid - specifically the read and create operations. I created a view model to store the values that I obtained from my Index controller and then used the view model to pass the values from kendogrid to the read and create operation controllers. For some reason, I was only able to pass parameters to the read operation using ajax.

Note: Still not the best solution. It calls readData controller twice and I don't want that.

Javascript

```
<Script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {    
                    url: "readData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",                  
                },
                create: {
                    url: "CreateInvoiceRecord?trxid=@Model.id2&bcid=@Model.id",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "itemID",
                    fields: {
                        ItemName: { type: "string" },
                        Amount: { type: "number", validation: { required: true } },
                        ProductLine: { type: "string" },
                        Status: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            aggregate: [{ field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }]
        });
        $("#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable:  true,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create", "save"],
            columns: [
                { field: "ItemName", title: "Item", width: "150px" },
                { field: "Amount", title: "Amount", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px", aggregates: ["sum"], footerTemplate: "Total Amount: #=sum#" },
                { field: "ProductLine", title: "Product Line", width: "150px", editor: productLineDropDownEditor},
                { field:  "Status", title: "Status", width: "150px", editor: statusDropDownEditor },
                { command:  "Update", title: "Update" , width:"150px"}],
            editable: true
        });
    });
    function productLineDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({              
                autoBind: false,
                valuePrimitive: true,
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "name",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Customs/getProdLines",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "Data",
                        model: {
                            fields: {}
                        }
                    },
                }
            });
    }
    function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
            var data = [
                { text: "Active", value: "1" },
                { text: "Paid", value: "2" },
                { text: "Cancelled", value: "3" }
            ]
            $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                valuePrimitive: true,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                autobind: false,
                dataSource: data
            });
    }
    //function testAjax() {     
    //}
    //data: { 'name': ItemName, 'amount': Amount, 'prodline': ProductLine, 'status': Status },
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        data: { id: "@Model.id", id2:"@Model.id2" },
        url: "readData/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (itemList) {
            console.log(itemList);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Model

```
Public Class MyViewModel
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property id2 As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The VB grid syntax from http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/vb#grid
is:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Of YourViewModelClassThatYouWantToBindTheGridTo)() _
    .Name("grid") _
    ...additional configuration.
```

You are missing the part where you tell the grid what type of object you are binding to(the "Of NameOfYourClass" part.

You should post your whole grid definition.

Also...C# syntax is sooooo much cleaner(I know that's not helpful).

**Edit**

OK, so this question isn't about the correct VB.NET Razor syntax anymore....

This is how you get "extra" data passed to the controller methods from a dataSource: you use the dataSource.transport.read.data configuration (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data)

Using an object:

```
transport: {
        read: {
            url: "TestAjax",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                parameterToPassToReadAction: valueYouWantToPassToReadAction
            }
        },
```

Using a function:

```
transport: {
        read: {
            url: "TestAjax",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: extraDataFunction
        },

function extraDataFunction () {
    return {
        parameterToPassToReadAction: valueYouWantToPassToReadAction
    };
}
```

Where parameterToPassToReadAction is the name of the parameter in your server method and valueYouWantToPassToReadAction is the value you want it to be...which is stored where ever you stored it when the page loaded.  If it is in a ViewModel of your vbhtml file and your javascript is in the script block of that same file, the syntax will be something like:

```
function extraDataFunction () {
    return {
        parameterToPassToReadAction: @Model.FieldYouWantToSend
    };
}
```

But it is not clear where you have this value stored.

Comment: Added the code for kendo! The errors are gone with the line associated with the html helper, but I think something is still wrong during run time. And then I still need to pass the individual variables to the read and create operations. data: (new {id = MyViewModel.id}) <= Don't know how to fix this yet either.

Comment: Are you sure that's your code? It's is a weird mix of Razor and javascript initialization that I'm not sure would work at all.  You are declaring the grid as bound to MyViewModel in Razor(in the document.ready) but then have the rest if the config in javascript with completely different columns and schema.  data: (new {id = MyViewModel.id}) is not javascript but it is in a chunk of javascript initialization code.  You need to first choose between using the ASP.NET MVC Razor initialization OR javascript initialization.  You can't mix them up the way are doing.

Comment: Well, I'm using Visual Studio to create a web app so I'm using html/javascript with the kendo grid inside the javascript code. Telerik has a lot of demos for their widgets, so I borrowed their code from here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing. I just modified it the way I wanted it since I thought that was the point of their demos. Check out the code and see if it clarifies anything up. I didn't realize it was using Razor. I thought it was only javascript. What I have so far all works, I just can't figure out how to pass through data in my model view to a controller using kendo.

Comment: This question has completely changed....it was originally about a Razor error and now it is not...I've update my answer to try and answer the new question.

Comment: Sorry that my question was so unclear. I was completely confused and wasn't totally sure what direction to head into, but your answers were extremely helpful. I followed your logic in a different question and it was very helpful (link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224176/trying-to-use-a-parameter-obtained-from-index-controller-and-passing-it-into-k/40224632?noredirect=1#comment67717879_40224632)